# Is there any way I can use google-image serach API?

Tags: c#, google-image-search

I want to retrive search results from google images from my .net application. Is there any way out there?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, there is.**

The Google Image Search API offers access through a RESTful interface, as described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje), on the API reference page.

You can use e.g. the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class to make the API calls, and use one of the JSON libraries as listed on [this page](http://www.json.org/), such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) or [JSONSharp](http://code.google.com/p/jsonsharp/) to parse the returned JSON data.

Comment: You could also use the WCF Rest Starter Kit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx and http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/wcf-rest