# google image search api in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, google-api

I got one api for google image search but that one is old and doesn't work in present google image search  so is there any latest api for google image search?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833988/is-there-any-way-i-can-use-google-image-serach-api

Answer (score 1):

Google Image Search Client in C# 5.0 and WPF (2011)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/259621/Google-Image-Search-Client-in-Csharp-5-0-and-WPF

Answer (score 0):

```
string imgurl = "https://fun.vin/frank-capra-jr";

        var documents = new HtmlWeb().Load(imgurl);
        var urls = (documents.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                        .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                        .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))).ToList();
        int c = 0;
         foreach(string a in urls)
        {
            string url = a;

            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                string imageUrl = url;
                //string saveLocation = @"C:\New folder (2)\car\someImage.jpg";

                byte[] imageBytes;
                HttpWebRequest imageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
                WebResponse imageResponse = imageRequest.GetResponse();

                Stream responseStream = imageResponse.GetResponseStream();

                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(responseStream))
                {
                    imageBytes = br.ReadBytes(500000);
                    br.Close();
                }
                responseStream.Close();
                imageResponse.Close();

                int Hight = 0;
                int wedht = 0;
                Image image = null;
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                {
                     image = Image.FromStream(stream);

                }
                ImageFormat ab = image.RawFormat;

                string ext = new ImageFormatConverter().ConvertToString(ab);

                //if (ImageFormat.Jpeg.Equals(image.RawFormat))
                //{
                //    // JPEG
                //}
                //else if (ImageFormat.Png.Equals(image.RawFormat))
                //{
                //    // PNG
                //}
                //else if (ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(image.RawFormat))
                //{
                //    // GIF
                //}
                Hight = image.Height;
                wedht = image.Width;
                if (!ImageFormat.Gif.Equals(image.RawFormat))
                {
                    string saveLocation = @"C:\New folder (2)\car\someImage" + c + "." + ext;// + "jpg";

                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
                    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                    try
                    {
                        bw.Write(imageBytes);
                        c++;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        fs.Close();
                        bw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```